# Add classes dynamically to the children by looping through div

Tags: jquery, css

I need a jquery script to add class dynamically to the 'div's' in the class row. The class is for setting margins. If there is two div's in class row add class to first one only, and If there is three 'div's' add class to two avoid third.

So the actual need is calculate the div's on the 'row' and add classes to div other than the last one. Here is my html:-

```
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="two-col">
                        <h3>Header 2/3 Column</h3>
                        <p>Kidney Cancer Canada is a charitable patient-led support organization established to improve the quality of life for patients and their 
                        families living with kidney cancer. <a href="#">Kidney Cancer Canada</a> advocates for access to netreatments, provides support and information to patients, 
                        funds much-needed research, and works to increase awareness of kidney cancer as a significant health issue. Our goal is to help patients navigate
                        through information about their disease and ensure they have access to new treatment options available to them.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one-col">
                        <h3>Header 1/3 Column</h3>
                        <p>KCC hosts patient and caregiver education meetings and webcasts from locations all across canada. Atttending meetings in-person provides an 
                        excellent oppurtunity to meet other kidney cancer patients, caregivers, and healthcare professionals</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="one-col">
                        <h3>Header 1/3 Column</h3>
                        <p>KCC hosts patient and caregiver education meetings and webcasts from locations all across canada. Atttending meetings in-person provides an 
                        excellent oppurtunity to meet other kidney cancer patients, caregivers, and healthcare professionals</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one-col">
                        <h3>Header 1/3 Column</h3>
                        <p>KCC hosts patient and caregiver education meetings and webcasts from locations all across canada. Atttending meetings in-person provides an 
                        excellent oppurtunity to meet other kidney cancer patients, caregivers, and healthcare professionals</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one-col">
                        <h3>Header 1/3 Column</h3>
                        <p>KCC hosts patient and caregiver education meetings and webcasts from locations all across canada. Atttending meetings in-person provides an 
                        excellent oppurtunity to meet other kidney cancer patients, caregivers, and healthcare professionals</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do the classes *actually* need to be dynamically added or is this just a case of not knowing how to apply CSS to everything but the last child of a collection so you're resorting to JS to hack it in?  If it must be dynamic, it would be more efficient to apply the class to the parent (`.row`) and modify the styles via `.row.newClass .one-col` or similar selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to apply that class to your `divs` with class `clear` then you can use this

```
$('div.row').find('div').addClass('yourclass').not(':last-child,.clear');
```

Or

```
$('div.row').find('div').addClass('yourclass').not(':last-child');
```

**[Live Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/VSM3w/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script to do this task:

```
    $.each($(".row"),function () {

      var length = $(this).find('.two-col').length+$(this).find('.one-col').length+$(this).find('.three-col').length;
          for(i=1;i<length;i++)
          {
             $(this).find(":nth-child("+i+")").addClass('margin-right');
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.row").each(function(){

 len = $(this).find("div").length ;
 if ($(this).find("div.clear").length > 0){
   len = len-1;
 }
 var i=0;
 $(this).find("div").each(function(){
 if($(this).attr("class") != "clear"){
 if (i < len-1 ){
     $(this).addClass("margin_class");
  }  
 }
 i++;

 });

});
```

Comment: In some div's there is <div class="clear"></div>, this will cause incorrect output